# Disabling ng-autocomplete (or disabling a div property in general)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, autocomplete

I have 2 buttons which select for 2 different cases I want to address.  When I select button #2 I want to disable the autocomplete feature on my input bar (which is enabled using ng-autocomplete) but I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this easily (without completely inserting a new div, which sounds like a bad idea).

I've tried setting the value to different things to no avail.  Is there a way to dynamically disable this?

Code in question:

```
<input id="businessID" type="text" ng-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete" placeholder="What business do you want to pay?">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea just came into my mind, and it think it could answer your question:

Create 2 inputs:

- One with ng-autocomplete

  ```
  <input ng-if="!disabled" id="businessID" type="text" ng-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete" placeholder="What business do you want to pay?">
  ```
- Second without

  ```
  <input ng-if="disabled" id="businessID" type="text" ng-model="autocomplete" placeholder="What business do you want to pay?">
  ```

Then in the inputs you can distinguish if disabled or not with an scope variable.That way when it is disabled you will see the normal one and when isn't the autocomplete one.

Regarding with the button, is as simple as this:

```
<button ng-click="disabled = !disabled">Disable autocomeplete</button>
```

Comment: This needs some tweaking to get it working smoothly for my purposes, but this absolutely pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you! (I'll award the bounty as soon as the timer is up for it)

Comment: Glad to hear that this helped you out